# Assign an external image to a Picturebox in Visual Studio 2008 (C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, picturebox

How can I assign an external image into the PictureBox in `Visual Studio 2008` ?
Typically, When we use `ChooseImage` in PictureBox , Visual Studio adds the image to the exe file and it causes increasing exe file's volume, I wanna add the image from a directory beside the exe file.
Is it possible in Visual Studio 2008?

P.S:
I don't want add the image with C# code, because VS2008 doesn't show it in developing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linked resources.

> When you add a linked resource, the
>   .resx file that stores your project
>   resource information includes only a
>   relative path to the resource file on
>   disk. If you add images, videos, or
>   other complex files as linked
>   resources, you can edit them using a
>   default editor that you associate with
>   that file type in the Resource
>   Designer. When you add an embedded
>   resource, the data is stored directly
>   in the project's resource (.resx)
>   file. Strings can only be stored as
>   embedded resources.embedded resources.

[MSDN on Linked vs. Embedded Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

P.S. I however still don't get why would you need it—even if .exe doesn't get bigger, the whole app package would have a bigger size, wouldn't it?

Best,
Dan

Comment: Bigger exe file runs with delay, isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think so. But if you're unsure, you can measure it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this in C# code using the [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd.aspx) method.  As long as the C# code is in the initialization of the form / control, it should run at both design time and run time.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to add the c# code into the `InitializeComponent()` ?

Comment: I've added this code `this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Images\flower4.png");` but it causes an error !!!

Comment: No you totally should not modify `InitializeComponent` code as it gets generated by designer. This line should be placed after this call in the constructor. What kind of error do you get? Please also see my answer about linked resources.

Comment: I would not use the relative file path you are using, I would use the full path: for example c:\MyProject\Images\flower4.png.  If you are putting the code inside of the InitializeComponent() routine the computer might not be looking in the right spot.

Comment: As an aside, gaearon is correct in that if you make any changes in the designer it will possibly delete without warning any code you have put in the InitializeComponent() method.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can get images from `Resources`</strike>

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.[image name];
```

see [How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)

Misread the question OP asked to load without using the Resources.

you will need to do

`Image.FromFile("c:\\image.bmp")`

If image if a JPEG then You can cast it to Bitmap

`Bitmap myJpeg=(Bitmap) Image.FromFile("myJpegPath");`

OR,

```
System.Drawing.Image loadImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("c:\\image.JPG");
loadImg.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: As I said I don't want to use `Resources` , because it increases the exe file volume.

Answer (score 1):

If this is WinForms, it's better to just set the [`ImageLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation.aspx) of the PictureBox to the path to your image.  Do this from the designer to have it show at design time.